# How to create write-once properties?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I'm stuck with a general OOP problem, and can't find the right way to phrase my question.

I want to create a class that gives me an object which I can write to once, persist it to storage and then be unable to change the properties. (for example: invoice information - once written to storage, this should be immutable). Not all information is available immediately, during the lifecycle of the object, information is added.

What I'd like to avoid is having exceptions flying out of setters when trying to write, because it feels like you're offering a contract you don't intend to keep.

Here are some ideas I've considered so far:

1. Pass in any write-information in the constructor. Constructor throws exception if the data is already present.
2. Create multiple classes in an inheritance tree, with each class representing the entity at some stage of its lifecycle, with appropriate setters where needed. Add a colletive interface for all the read operations.
3. Silently discarding any inappropriate writes.

My thoughts on these:
1. Makes the constructor highly unstable, generally a bad idea.
2. Explosion of complexity, and doesn't solve the problem completely (you can call the setter twice in a row, within the same request)
3. Easy, but same problem as with the exceptions; it's all a big deception towards your clients.

(Just FYI: I'm working in PHP5 at the moment - although I suspect this to be a generic problem)

Comment: Would you care to elaborate? If domain-driven design has an answer to this conundrum, I do not yet see it.

Comment: DDD doesn't answer anything by itself, instead it gives you another way of looking at problems. To know, out of any language-related thinking, exacly what you want is the key to success in any application. Anyway, I wouldn't go for any of those options.

Comment: Are you sure you would never need to modify an invoice once entered, like if someone made a data entry error they'd like to fix?

Comment: Hi Jasper - Yes, I'm quite positive. The invoice data is exported to a third party system through a webservice, which can then process them. The only way we allow manual corrections is through admin intervention, so that we can guarantee both systems are in sync - this is an explicit business requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting problem. I think your best choice was #1, but I'm not sure I'd do it in the constructor. That way the client code can choose what it wants to do with the exception (suppress them, handle them, pass them up to the caller, etc...). And if you don't like exceptions, you could move the writing to a `write()` method that returns `true` if the write was successful and `false` otherwise.

Comment: So what you're saying is the original idea, with the setters throwing the exception is OK? It's better than the constructor, anyway. The write() method sounds interesting... It's not that I'm completely opposed to exceptions, it's just that they seem fairly heavy-handed for this situation - having to be aware of exceptions every time you set a property on these objects can get tedious very quickly I can image.

Comment: @kander: I would assume that whoever is using this code would know that these are write-once, so throwing an exception might be a good thing as it lets the user know they did something very naughty. Another option would be to quietly log the second-write somewhere, but that adds dependencises on your logging system. But depending on usage, it might be better to have the app blow up in a splatter of stack traces than to silently suppress incorrect usage of write-once objects.